# How to enable Calendar sync with microsoft? (Windows 10)

Tags: sync, windows-10, calendar, windows-10-upgrade, ios

I selected custom settings, and disabled the 1st option in the custom settings : `Sync contacts/calendar and other data with microsoft` during the windows 10 upgrade from windows 7.

I've upgraded to windows 10, and have added my microsoft outlook account to both my windows 10 calendar app and my iphone settings. But the events are not syncing.... I tried adding a test event on my windows 10 calendar app, but it didn't sync over to the ios. I checked it's (win10) settings and the setting for the account are only "download content" not sync/upload content. I think this maybe due to the custom setting disabled during the upgrade installation.

Also, another option was that the calendar weather data was in Fahrenheit, while I have set my settings to metric in the control panel settings. There are no settings for the weather in the calendar app, so I don't know how to enable metric system for the weather displayed in the calendar. The separate weather app displays the metric via it's own option, but the calendar app doesn't.

Any way to solve these two errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the article [How To Sync iCloud Calendar With Windows 10 Calendar App](https://miapple.me/sync-icloud-calendar-windows-10-calendar-app/).

It explains why the sync doesn't work and describes a workaround for syncing iCloud calendar with Windows 10 calendar app, but with the restriction of ‘read-only’ calendar syncing.

If that's not enough for you, you will need to wait for Microsoft to improve
the implementation of its CalDAV and CardDAV protocols for calendar.
As they are already working for Mail, it is probably just a bug that should
be solved soon enough, since the problem was already signaled to Microsoft.

Comment: To the masked downvoter: If you have a better idea, please give your answer. If you are sure the answer is wrong, please state why. Otherwise, please refrain from downvoting.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote you, although you might have been downvoted by someone else because the miapple link you posted has another link in the comments by the author about the CalDAV & CardDAV protocols enabled in the new win10 build (Blog post dated May 31): [Windows 10 Will Support CalDAV And CardDAV For iCloud And Google](https://miapple.me/windows-10-will-support-caldav-and-carddav-for-icloud-and-google/).

Comment: I didn't think it was you. We might never know why the answer was downvoted. There is no conflict with that link, as evidently in W10 there was an effort to work with these protocols, only that the implementation still has some problems and is not functional for all cases, as mail works but not the calendar.

Comment: The message I tried to pass was this : Either use a non-100% workaround, or wait for Microsoft.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will use the read only method until two way sync is available on Windows 10.

Comment: Well, the issue seems to have been resolved at the Microsoft end, and I'm now able to sync two ways easily between ios and win10... Thanks anyways! I'll add the +50 to your answer, although I believe you should edit it to the updated answer from the blog post I mentioned in comments above (Windows 10 now supports CalDAV and Cardav)! I request you edit your answer, so that I can add the +50 to your answer tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: You can vote for the CalDAV feature in Windows 10 Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/Mwsspk
Hope it will be addressed.